# A faster way than "for loop" - Indexing 3d numpy array by 2d array

Tags: numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-indexing

I have a 3d `(3, 2, 3)` array and first dimension(**3**) is flexible it can be any size.

```
arr = np.array(
[[[56, 24, 32],
  [56, 24, 32]],
 [[51, 27, 72],
  [51, 27, 72]],
 [[36, 14, 49],
  [36, 14, 49]]])
```

Indexing array is `(2,3)`:

```
idxs = np.array(
[[1, 0, 2],
 [2, 1, 0]])
```

I wanna index **arr** by **idxs**. Expected result is :

```
[[[24 56 32]
  [32 24 56]]
 [[27 51 72]
  [72 27 51]]
 [[14 36 49]
  [49 14 36]]])
```

If i use for loop like below it takes a lot of time :

```
for i, arr2d in enumerate(arr):
    for j, (arr1d, idx) in enumerate(zip(arr2d, idxs)):
        arr[i, j] = arr1d[idx]
```

So my question is : ***How can i speed up this process ?***

Comment: *arr* has a redundant axis: `np.squeeze(arr[:,::2])[:,idxs]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(arr, idxs[None, ...], 2)
Out[]: 
array([[[24, 56, 32],
        [32, 24, 56]],

       [[27, 51, 72],
        [72, 27, 51]],

       [[14, 36, 49],
        [49, 14, 36]]])
```